# Trouble selecting an element for overriding

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint

In a SharePoint list page I'm trying to override what happens on the 'Edit Item' icon and go to my own URL.

The full element looks like this:

```
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="ms-cui-ctl-large " aria-describedby="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit_ToolTip" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit-Large"><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer"><span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float"><img unselectable="on" alt="" src="/_layouts/inc/1033/ipfsimages.png" style="top: -32px; left: -32px;"></span></span><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Edit<br>Item</span></a>
```

I've matched other elements on the same page without issue. This particular one is being difficult.

I have tried both of these ways but not getting it:

```
$('a[id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit-Large"]').removeAttr("onclick").click(function() {
            location.href = "https://mycustomurl";
        });


$('a[id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit-Large"]').attr('href','https://mycustomurl');
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `onclick` attribute, I notice that is returning false, so not bubbling, or following the href.

`.attr("onclick", "")`

```js
$('a[id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit-Large"]').attr('href', 'www.google.ca').attr("onclick", "");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a unselectable="on" href="javascript:;" onclick="return false;" class="ms-cui-ctl-large " aria-describedby="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit_ToolTip" mscui:controltype="Button" role="button" id="Ribbon.ContextualTabs.InfoPathListDisplayTab.Manage.Controls.btnEdit-Large"><span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largeIconContainer"><span unselectable="on" class=" ms-cui-img-32by32 ms-cui-img-cont-float"><img unselectable="on" alt="" src="/_layouts/inc/1033/ipfsimages.png" style="top: -32px; left: -32px;"></span></span>
  <span unselectable="on" class="ms-cui-ctl-largelabel">Edit<br>Item</span>
</a>
```

Comment: thanks but it still doesn't match.  Must be that SharePoint is doing other stuff first and what I'm seeing as the html output is a final rendering.